# Syslog start logging in the morning! why?

Tags: 18.04, server, syslog, logrotate

Hello I've a Ubuntu server 18.04 running. But the problem is syslog start logging at every morning not at 00:00 midnight!

````
Jan  5 06:25:03 localhost snmpd[810]: truncating integer value > 32 bits
Jan  5 06:29:04 localhost snmpd[810]: message repeated 14 times: [ truncating integer value > 32 bits]
Jan  5 06:30:01 localhost CRON[10230]: (root) CMD (   PATH="$PATH:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin/" pihole updatechecker local)
Jan  5 06:30:04 localhost snmpd[810]: truncating integer value > 32 bits
Jan  5 06:35:04 localhost snmpd[810]: message repeated 17 times: [ truncating integer value > 32 bits]
Jan  5 06:36:03 localhost snmpd[810]: truncating integer value > 32 bits
Jan  5 06:38:04 localhost snmpd[810]: message repeated 8 times: [ truncating integer value > 32 bits]
Jan  5 06:39:01 localhost CRON[10288]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
Jan  5 06:39:04 localhost snmpd[810]: truncating integer value > 32 bits
Jan  5 06:39:04 localhost snmpd[810]: message repeated 2 times: [ truncating integer value > 32 bits]```
````

Comment: This is normal. The log rotation time is usually 6:25am local. Would you like to change it to midnight, instead? That's not too difficult.

Comment: Yes! my other server starts logging at 00:00. how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to have your logs rotate at midnight every day, you'll need to make some changes to your `/etc/crontab` file. This is the basic structure that you'll find as part of a default installation:

```
...
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# Example of job definition:
# .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7) OR sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  * user-name command to be executed
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
```

The daily actions happen at 6:25am, the weekly actions happen at 6:47am every Sunday, the monthly actions happen on the 1st at 6:52am. So, to modify the daily log rotation time, you will want to change:

```
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron ...
```

To:

```
 0 0    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron ...
```

Be sure to change *just* the numbers. Nothing else should be modified. Once this is complete, a reboot may be necessary just to ensure that the crontab is properly loaded.

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing this out. Really appreciate you help!